# Applying for Huawei ID and Health Kit

Tags: release, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery, appgallery-connect

Is it necessary to apply for both services if my app is not going to the App Gallery or Play Store?
I'm mainly developing this app for a college presentation so its not going to be released at all.

Answer (score 1):

When an app is running, it verifies the permission and fingerprint certificate. Therefore, you need to apply for an app ID and enable related services to use the app, regardless of whether you want to release it on the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the majority of HMS Kits, it is necessary that the desired app services are enabled and properly configured on your Huawei Developer Account. This is the case regardless if you plan to release your app or not. Furthermore, this is the general process of most mobile development when you are linking your app to a mobile API backend.

Comment: Do you have any idea on how long does the review time takes? im currently sitting on 3 days

Comment: @Juancarlord It depends, usually it will take 2-5 days. If any questions, you can open a help ticket in AGC console. Let me know if you need help on how to open help ticket.

Comment: Yes, I would some help in order to open a ticket if I don't get a response tomorrow